# Pokemon with unusually high attack?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a Horsea with a Bubble attack of 25, but according to [this page](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/horsea.html) the attack should only be 15.

Is the webpage inaccurate, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Niantic just recently changed a lot of moves' power so some information online could be out of date. For an updated version of move powers check [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4v99uo/move_powers_have_been_updated/).